# Cannot assign to 'GetUserByIdModel' because it is not a variable

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to populate a model but am getting the error Cannot assign to 'GetUserByIdModel' because it is not a variable.

This is my model

```
export class GetUserByIdModel {
  firstname: string;
  lastname: string;
  nationalityId: number;
  identityTypeId: number;
  identityValue: string;
  titleId: number;
  genderId: number;
  contactChannels: Array<ContactChannel>;
}

export class ContactChannel {
  type: number;
  value: string;
}
```

I then import it in a service file and try to use it

declarations

```
userDetails: GetUserByIdModel;
```

function

```
  getUserDetails(userId): Observable<GetUserByIdModel> {l
    const token = this._storeService.getStoredData().id_token;
    const headers = new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`)
      .set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    const options = { headers: headers };
    const url = `${this.candidateUrl}/Get/${userId}`;
    this._http.get<any>(url, options).subscribe((resp) => {
    this.userDetails: GetUserByIdModel = {
      firstname: resp.firstname,
      lastname: resp.lastname,
      nationalityId: resp.firstname,
      identityTypeId: resp.identityTypeId,
      identityValue: resp.identityValue,
      titleId: resp.titleId,
      genderId: resp.genderId,
      contactChannels: [
        { type: 1, value: resp[0].value },
        { type: 2, value: resp[1].value }
      ],
    };
  })

    return new Observable((observer) => {
      observer.next(this.userDetails);
      observer.complete();
    });
  }
```

I see the error on this line `this.userDetails: GetUserByIdModel = {...`

Please assist

Comment: Try with changing `this._http.get<any>` to `this._http.get<GetUserByIdModel>`

Comment: Tried it, still same error :(

Comment: Make all fields inside class nullable. like firstname?: string;
  lastname?: string; same in ContactChannel class also or better to use an interface instead of class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove type of `this.userDetails: GetUserByIdModel -> this.userDetails = {..}` since it's already at the declaration and make the fields nullables `firstName?, lastName?`...